# Error executing query in tuProlog

Tags: java, prolog, tuprolog

i downloaded the tuprolog and i'm not able to get the result for the following query, while i get answer in PROL ide.. can someone help?

```
verb(admit-1).
verb(work-4).
nsubjpass(admit-1, patient-2).
agent(admit-1, doctor-3).
nsubj(work-4, who-5).
aux(work-4, be-6).
rcmod(doctor-3, work-4).
prep_in(work-4, clinic-7).


aggregation('part of').
aggregation('belongs to').
aggregation('subdivision of').
aggregation('have').
aggregation('contain').
aggregation('comprise').
aggregation('include').
aggregation('define').
aggregation('consist of').
aggregation('compose of').
aggregation('denote by').
aggregation('identify by').
aggregation('make up of').
aggregation('record with').

attribute('have').
attribute('contain').
attribute('comprise').
attribute('include').
attribute('define').
attribute('consist of').
attribute('compose of').
attribute('denote by').
attribute('identify by').
attribute('make up of').
attribute('record with').

generalization('be').
generalization('kind of').
generalization('type of').
generalization('classify into').
generalization('consider').

object(X) :- noun(X).
relation(X) :-  verb(X).
rel(X,Y) :- nsubjpass(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- agent(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- nsubj(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- aux(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- rcmod(X,Y).
rel(X,Y) :- prep_in(X,Y).

associatedWith(X,Y) :- rel(X,Y).
associatedWith(X,Y,Z) :- verb(Y),associatedWith(X,Y), associatedWith(Y,Z).
associatedWith(X,Y,Z) :- verb(X),associatedWith(X,Y), associatedWith(X,Z).
rel_aggregation(X,Y,R):-rel(X,Y).aggregation(R).

?- associatedWith(X,Y,Z).
```

i need to handle these kind of relations and get the output to process again in java

can anyone please tell me how to integrate prolog and java?

EDIT:
i get this error in tuprolog by implementing the code

this code works for associatedWith(X,Y). i.e with 2 arguments, but doesnt work when i give 3 arguments associatedWith(X,Y,Z). what to do.. pls help i get this exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: alice.tuprolog.Var cannot be cast to alice.tuprolog.Struct
        at alice.tuprolog.lib.BasicLibrary.agent_2(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at alice.tuprolog.PrimitiveInfo.evalAsPredicate(Unknown Source)
        at alice.tuprolog.StateGoalEvaluation.doJob(Unknown Source)
        at alice.tuprolog.Engine.run(Unknown Source)
        at alice.tuprolog.EngineManager.solve(Unknown Source)
        at alice.tuprolog.Prolog.solve(Unknown Source)
        at javaapplication9.Main.main(Main.java:26)
Exception in thread "main" alice.tuprolog.NoSolutionException
        at alice.tuprolog.SolveInfo.getSolution(Unknown Source)
        at javaapplication9.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main tuProlog objects you need to handle in Java are: `Theory`, that you can use to represent a Prolog program; `Prolog`, that is the interpreter which you will ask queries to; and `SolveInfo`, containing data for each solution found by the interpreter.

Let's suppose your Prolog program (i.e. all the code you posted except the last line) is contained in a file named `theory.pl`. Roughly speaking (i.e. modulo imports and exceptions), the procedure you need to follow is similar to:

```
Prolog engine = new Prolog();
Theory theory = new Theory(new FileInputStream("theory.pl"));
engine.setTheory(theory);
SolveInfo solution = engine.solve("associatedWith(X, Y, Z).");
if (solution.isSuccess()) {
    System.out.println(solution.getTerm("X"));
    System.out.println(solution.getTerm("Y"));
    System.out.println(solution.getTerm("Z"));
}
```

If your query possibly yields more than one solution, use a `while` loop to test the existence of open choice points with `Prolog.hasOpenAlternatives` and retrieve another solution with `Prolog.solveNext`.

Chapter 8 in the manual (a PDF file you should find in the `doc` subdirectory of any tuProlog distribution) contains lots of small examples of increasing complexity about interacting with Prolog from Java code (see in particular Section 8.4).

Comment: this code works for associatedWith(X,Y). i.e with 2 arguments, but doesnt work when i give 3 arguments associatedWith(X,Y,Z). what to do.. pls help

Comment: have added the exception in my main question.. please say wht to do

Answer (score 3):

agent/2 is a built-in predicate in tuProlog - you could try renaming your version.

Comment: I'm torn. This answer apparently fixed the OP's problem but it's not marked as correct. The other answer helped me understand tuProlog.. upvotes for allll

Comment: @ataulm the original question was about the integration of Prolog and Java, which I answered to. Then, the question was edited to add an exception asking for help, which I ignored but was given by this answer.